# How do I delete lines matching multiple pattern in text file using bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pattern-matching

I have a text file and want to delete lines that start with A, T, G or C. If it's only `A`, I could have done like this `sed '/A/d' infile.txt`, but how do you delete lines that start with A,T,G or C letters?

Comment: Use `grep -v "^[ATGC]"`. Look up the manual page for `grep` for a description of options.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed '/^[ATGC]/d' infile.txt
```

Or `grep`:

```
grep -v '^[ATGC]'
```

Or `bash` itself:

```
while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ^[ATGC] ]] || echo "$line"; done < infile.txt
```